# Convert float to string in php?

Tags: php, string, floating-point, type-conversion

Like:

```
float(1.2345678901235E+19) => string(20) "12345678901234567890"
```

Can it be done?

(it's for json_decode...)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
echo number_format($float,0,'.','');
```

note: this is for integers, increase 0 for extra fractional digits

Comment: This is a good solution if you want to have a maximum number of decimal places.  Based on the question, I'd change the above to `echo number_format($float,10,'.','');` giving it a max of 10 decimal places. (Arbitrary, but I'm pretty sure it should be higher than 0).

Comment: The json value I get is not float, it's a really big integer, like 23453453245324532453253425. But it gets converted to float by json_decode. Will your solution always get me the original json value? :)  (it seems to work though for the data I have now)

Comment: floats have a limited precision, once your integers are large enough it won't work. should work for approx 14 digits. beyond that it might work, but could be sheer luck.

Comment: The value has 17 numbers right now. Do you know when it will stop to precisely convert the float?

Comment: You can change the setting in the function call, see my answer.

Comment: are these originally floats? because then they already lost precision. if they are ints try to send them as strings.

Comment: [`number_format` docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Answer (score 20):

```
$float = 0.123;
$string = sprintf("%.3f", $float); // $string = "0.123";
```

Answer (score 2):

It turns out [`json_decode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) by default casts large integers as floats. This option can be overwritten in the function call:

```
$json_array = json_decode($json_string, , , 1);
```

I'm basing this only on the main documentation, so please test and let me know if it works.

Comment: that's the first thing I tried - JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING, and I get: json_decode expects at most 3 parameters bla bla... and a undefined constant message

Comment: Ha! I just tested and I got the same error, but with "expects at most 2 parameters". It looks like the 3rd parameter was added in 5.3 and the 4th in 5.4.  So it would work if we upgraded our php.

Comment: Anyway, it's not even valid code, you can't omit arguments like that.

Comment: can't you?  It says I passed in 4 parameters... Let me do a test.

Answer (score 0):

A double precision floating point number can only contain around 15 significant digits.  The best you could do is pad the extra digits out with zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by passing the argument `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` for the `options` parameter.

`json_decode($json, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING)`

See example #5 in the [json_decode documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Answer (score 0):

The only way to decode a float without losing precision is to go through the json and frame all the floats in quotation marks. By making strings of numbers.

[PHP json_decode integers and floats to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108803/php-json-decode-integers-and-floats-to-string/65057385#65057385)